# How do I know when to use resource generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

Please, I would like to know when to choose resource generator over controller generator.

From my understanding, controller generator create controller, model and views with some methods

However, resource generator create the same empty items (controller, model and view).

At what point I need to choose over one over the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "resource generator"? There is a generator for controllers, one for models and one called "scaffold". I am not aware of one called "resources". `resources` is a method used in the `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks @clara. There is a resource generator that generates controller, view. However, controller, model, and view will be empty kind of. Run the command "rails g resource Book title:string " and see the result compare to when you run the command "rails g controller category science art"